# Flash scroll indicators while scrolling to the top

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

When I tap the status bar to the scroll to the top of a UIScrollView, the scroll indicators appear as it scrolls and then disappear once it stops.

When I programmatically scroll to the top using `[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES]`, the scroll indicators disappear as it scrolls to the top.

Is there any way to programmatically produce similar behavior to what happens when the user taps on the status bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is and is exactly called like you actually presumed.

From the `UIScrollView` Reference

```
flashScrollIndicators
```

> Displays the scroll indicators momentarily.
>
> - (void)flashScrollIndicators
>
> Discussion You should call this method whenever you bring the scroll view to front.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later. Declared In
> UIScrollView.h

Comment: I should have mentioned it, but I had tried `[scroll flashScrollIndicators];` immediately before and after `[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES]`, without success.

Comment: I am just guessing here, but maybe the "before" and "after" were too early. Maybe you should handle the UIScrollView-delegation of a didScroll and flash at that point to make sure the scrolling-animation doesn't interfere.

Comment: That did the trick. I call `[scroll flashScrollIndicators];` every time I get a didScroll message, until we're at the top. Thanks!